# Create a GET request that retrieves the data of a particular user data

Tags: javascript, html, express, node-persist

I want to create a GET request that retrives data of particular user form user data and make that request from the browser as well

In browser need to get like this..

For example: localhost:3000/user/5

Then browser will print like

User details

User id:5
Name:Ann

Comment: This kind of posting is undesired in SO, as there's no direct question or technical attempt. You should first be Googling tutorials on this topic, like "javascript ajax request tutorial"; there's 100's of articles. as well learn about HTML `fetch`. When you have actual code to share and a technical problem to ask about, that is a more suitable SO post.

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve the data of a particular user from DB.

Here is an example:
`GET /users/{id}`

```
router.get("/users/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const data = await Model.findById(id);
    return res.send(data);
  }catch(err){
    return res.send(err);  
}
});
```

id is the identifier of the user. The request will return the data of a particular user.

[refer the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/retrieve/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20read%20operations,()%20or%20findOne()%20methods.)

Comment: Why are you giving a MongoDB answer to a question that doesn’t mention MongoDb but is tagged node-persist?